# Slide In/Out Navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a slide in/out side navigation for my website. It works fine as it is just now, but I was hoping to get the site to move over with the sidebar (similar to this: http://demo.agnidesigns.com/fortune/demo15/). Currently it just moves out over the site.

I thought maybe I could add a toggle classList function which would move the sections left to the same width as the sidebar (left: 280px), but can't quite understand how to include that in the JS. However I am certain it will be a similar method to my existing JS for the side navigation toggle.

```
    <nav>


        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">

                <div id="navBar">
                    <div id="navBtn">
                        <img id="navLogo" src="resources/img/logo-white.svg">
                    </div>
                    <div id="navText">
                        <h2>Menu</h2>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="social-links">

                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            </div>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#overview"><h2>Who Are We</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#web"><h2>Services</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#drone"><h2>UAV</h2></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </nav>

<section class="section-overview new-section__whitetwothird" id="overview">
    <div class="row">

      <h2>Some Text</h2>
    </div>


</section>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 7px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 180%;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.new-section__whitetwothird {
      padding: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
     background-color: #fff;
     min-height: 66.66vh;
     width: calc(100vw - 80px);
     left: 80px;
    }

  #sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    left: -200px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sidebar a {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#navText h2:first-of-type{
    padding: 0;
}
#sidebar h2 {
    padding: 20px;
}

#navBar .icon {
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0;
}

.social-links {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 14px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.social-links li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 15% 0 0 0;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}

#navBar {
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

#navBar #navLogo {
    margin: 25%;
}

img {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 45%;
    margin: 40% 0;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: #fff;
}
```

JS

```
function toggleSidebar() {
    document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/BEpBzZ

I was curious if I would have to create a new function or can I extend my toggleSidebar with an else if?

I have tried adding a toggleSection() to the section but as the sidebar is already hooked up to another function it just stops working altogether, as well as trying to add a .section.active class (as I was trying to recreate the same thing as #sidebar.active:

```
.section.active {
    left: 280px;
}
```

Essentially the left: 280px is what I'm trying to make happen when the sidebar is opened/active.

Please excuse me if this looks silly, I am new to JS and still learning how things work, and cannot find anything online regarding what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add onto the existing `toggleSidebar()` function offsetting the content by adding a `left` property to the new `.new-section__whitetwothird--active` class ( you can amend the class name to better fit your project)

Update: I have added a querySelectorAll and a loop to add the class in the event where there are multiple classes with the same name on one page ( my previous answer was just `querySelector`) there are endless ways to add a loop I chose the older way rather than a newer version for better browser support.

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").classList.toggle("active");
  var sections = document.querySelectorAll(".new-section__whitetwothird"),i;
  for (i = 0; i < sections.length; ++i) {
    sections[i].classList.toggle("new-section__whitetwothird--active");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 7px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 180%;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.new-section__whitetwothird {
      padding: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
     background-color: #fff;
     min-height: 66.66vh;
     width: calc(100vw - 80px);
     left: 80px;
     transition:.5s ease;
       
    }

.new-section__whitetwothird--active {
  left:280px; 
}

#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    left: -200px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#sidebar a {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#navText h2:first-of-type{
    padding: 0;
}
#sidebar h2 {
    padding: 20px;
}

#navBar .icon {
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0;
}

.social-links {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 14px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.social-links li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 15% 0 0 0;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
}

#navBar {
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

#navBar #navLogo {
    margin: 25%;
}

img {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 45%;
    margin: 40% 0;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
        <nav>


            <div id="sidebar">
                <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">

                    <div id="navBar">
                        <div id="navBtn">
                            <img id="navLogo" src="resources/img/logo-white.svg">
                        </div>
                        <div id="navText">
                            <h2>Menu</h2>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="social-links">

                            <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-instagram"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#overview"><h2>Who Are We</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#web"><h2>Services</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#drone"><h2>UAV</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about"><h2>About Us</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#hire"><h2>Studio Hire</h2></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact"><h2>Contact Us</h2></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>

    <section class="section-overview new-section__whitetwothird" id="overview">
        <div class="row">

          <h2>Some Text</h2>
        </div>


    </section>
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work on mine but I will keep trying, thanks for your help! I knew it would be something simple.

Comment: Have you added the styles from `.new-section__whitetwothird--active` as well as the new javascript snippet?

Comment: Thats it working fine now, I must have had a typo somewhere!

Comment: Could you explain to me why it only works with the first named section? It seems to only work on one even when I add the class name to other sections?

Comment: ah, if you have more than one `.new-section__whitetwothird`  class in your document then you will need to use a slightly different snippet - I will update my origin answer to take this into account

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the trouble. Appreciated.

Comment: I have updated my snippet - my original answer used `querySelector` which insinuated there would only ever be one element with that class name on a page but in your case where there are multiple classes we need to use `querySelectorAll` we then have all of the elements with that class name so we need to run a loop that goes through each one in the list and toggles the classname - there are other ways to optimise this code .i.e. only toggling the class for the element that's coming into view rather than all of the elements - but I didn't want to veer too far away from your original code.

Comment: Fab, I'll have a look into that actually as it may help once I'm a bit further into it.

Answer (score 0):

By just re-arranging some of your html and adding some new lines, this is what I got.

This is how I changed your html

```
 <!--I created a main content wrapper and its height and width is the viewport-->
<main>
        <nav>
          <!--I placed the toggle btn here -->
          <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
            <div id="navBar">
              <div id="navBtn">
                <img id="navLogo" src="resources/img/logo-white.svg">
              </div>
              <div id="navText">
                  <h2>Menu</h2>
              </div>

              <ul class="social-links">
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-instagram"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="sidebar">
             <!--This is where the toggle button before -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#overview"><h2>Who Are We</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#web"><h2>Services</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#drone"><h2>UAV</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#about"><h2>About Us</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#hire"><h2>Studio Hire</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><h2>Contact Us</h2></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
       <!-- I created this main section wrapper that will hold all the sections-->
        <div class="section-wrapper">
          <section class="section-overview" id="overview">
              <div class="row">
                <h2>Section 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem tenetur error at ut, dolorem laborum dicta iste repellendus eaque! </p>
              </div>
          </section>

        </div>
      </main>
```

And these are the changes to the css

```
.section-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll; // will create the scrollbar if it overflows
  transition: transform .5s ease;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

// instead of targeting the #sidebar, I targeted the nav
nav.active {
  width: 360px;
}

nav.active+.section-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(280px); // this will push the sections to the right
}
```

All in all, I just replace some padding and margin properties to your css. 
And in your javascript, I simply replaced the targeted element to `nav`

And the result will be this

```js
function toggleSidebar() {
          document.querySelector('nav').classList.toggle('active');
  
 }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 180%;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.section-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

section {
    padding: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    }

nav {
  width: 80px;
  background: #000;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

nav.active {
  width: 360px;
}

nav.active+.section-wrapper {
  transform: translateX(280px);
}

#sidebar {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 100vh;
    left: -200px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-right: 80px;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav.active #sidebar {
  left: 0;
}

#sidebar a {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#sidebar li {
  list-style: none;
}

#navText h2:first-of-type{
    padding: 0;
}
#sidebar h2 {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#navBar .icon {
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0;
}

.social-links {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 14px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.social-links li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 15% 0 0 0;
}

.toggle-btn {
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  border-left: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
}

#navBar {
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

#navBar #navLogo {
    margin: 25%;
}

img {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 45%;
    margin: 40% 0;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    font-size: 7px;;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <main>
        <nav>
          <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="toggleSidebar()">
            <div id="navBar">
              <div id="navBtn">
                <img id="navLogo" src="resources/img/logo-white.svg">
              </div>
              <div id="navText">
                  <h2>Menu</h2>
              </div>
    
              <ul class="social-links">
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-logo-instagram"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#overview"><h2>Who Are We</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#web"><h2>Services</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#drone"><h2>UAV</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#about"><h2>About Us</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#hire"><h2>Studio Hire</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><h2>Contact Us</h2></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="section-wrapper">
          <section class="section-overview" id="overview">
              <div class="row">
                <h2>Section 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem tenetur error at ut, dolorem laborum dicta iste repellendus eaque! </p>
              </div>
          </section>
          <section class="section-overview" id="overview">
              <div class="row">
                <h2>Section 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem tenetur error at ut, dolorem laborum dicta iste repellendus eaque! </p>
              </div>
          </section>
          <section class="section-overview" id="overview">
              <div class="row">
                <h2>Section 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem tenetur error at ut, dolorem laborum dicta iste repellendus eaque! </p>
              </div>
          </section>
          <section class="section-overview" id="overview">
              <div class="row">
                <h2>Section 4</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil inventore porro illum, numquam expedita debitis veritatis quod? Inventore, optio. Vitae nihil consequatur error provident in, maxime earum dolores rerum aliquam sed magnam quibusdam harum nam. Modi rem eligendi saepe, atque sequi similique itaque voluptas a illum, placeat mollitia obcaecati praesentium? </p>
              </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </main>
```

By the way this is the pen I forked. I hope it helps https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVEYQM